# CSS overlay on revolution slider slides

Tags: html, css, slider, revolution-slider

I have been having a confused moment with some CSS which, as far as I can see should work fine.

I have a revolution slider which generates the slides and puts an overlay on each slide. I want the overlay on some slides and not on others so have put a class on the preceeding element (li) at runtime called `noOverlay`. The child div (the overlay, with a class called `slotholder`) has css applied to it, in the form of an `::after`, to apply the overlay as a background. I have created another css declaration which selects the `slotholder::after` via the parent div.

Problem is, the css doesnt seem to be applied.

You can see the live page here http://wwtw.org.uk/woa

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Code is as follows; (the first css declaration gives all the slides the overlay, the second, i was hoping, would remove it)

**CSS:**

```
.banner .rev_slider .slotholder:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    /* black overlay with 50% transparency */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.noOverlay .slotHolder:after {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li data-transition="fade" 
        data-slotamount="5" 
        data-masterspeed="700"
        data-title="Slide 1" 
        class="noOverlay tp-revslider-slidesli active-revslide" 
        style="width: 100%; 
                height: 100%; 
                overflow: hidden; 
                z-index: 20; 
                visibility: inherit; 
                opacity: 1; 
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">
    <div class="slotholder" 
            style="position: absolute; 
                    top: 0px; 
                    left: 0px; 
                    z-index: 0; 
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 100%; 
                    visibility: inherit; 
                    opacity: 1; 
                    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <!-- Runtime Modification - Img tag is Still Available for SEO Goals in Source - 
            <img src="https://wwtwcrushcmsstorage.blob.core.windows.net/wwtwcrushcmsstoragecontainer/Eh0CWQwmpodvMvUmC0K3lIpQB3pm.jpg&#10;" 
                    alt="Starting in L.A. - 1000 Miles - 12 Weeks" 
                    data-bgposition="center center" 
                    data-bgfit="cover" 
                    data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" 
                    data-bgparallax="10" 
                    class="rev-slidebg defaultimg" 
                    data-no-retina="">-->
    </div>
</li>
```